# ListItem not working with winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

I just simply trying to add items with values to a `combobox` from a XML file at runtime in a
windows application. The code below does not work in windows development.

//Code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Yourxmlfile.xml");

var query = from xEle in xDoc.Descendants("publication")
            select new ListItem(xEle.Element("name").Value,
                                xEle.Attribute("tcmid").Value);

cmbLoad.ValueMember = "value";
cmbLoad.DisplayMember = "text";
cmbLoad.DataSource = query;
```

In the above code the `ListItem` class is not available for winforms so i couldn't proceed.

The above code works fine with web application.

Any help?

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: "Does not work" is not descriptive enough for us to help. Please describe the symptom further so we can help you diagnose what is going on.

Comment: And can you post a sample XML?

Comment: @Szymon: The issue is with the class ListItem when using winforms.

Comment: @Santhoshkumar : I hope ListItem can be use in  System.Web.UI.WebControls and you are using it in windows where in Windows forms it will take obejct.

Comment: @VDN: Nope. Not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using this code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Yourxmlfile.xml");
var query = from xEle in xDoc.Descendants("publication")
            select new { value = xEle.Element("name").Value, text = xEle.Attribute("tcmid").Value };
var list = query.ToList();

comboBox1.ValueMember = "value";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "text";
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
```

`ListItem` doesn't exist for WinForms. I used an anonymous class above and converted it to a list which I can use as a source for a combo box.